# print figures side by side in a loop

Tags: c++

So I wrote my code where I have to get right triangles in different position . This is my code below :

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{

    for ( int i = 1 ; i <= 10 ; ++i ) {                       

      for ( int j = 1 ; j <= i ; j++ ) {

          if ( j <= i ) 

            cout << "*";

      }

      cout << endl;
  }

    cout <<"\n";

     for ( int i = 10 ; i >= 1 ; --i ) {

       for ( int j = 1 ; j <= i ; j++ ) {

        cout << "*";  
       }
      cout << endl;
  }

   cout <<"\n";

   int i , j;

   for (  i = 1 ; i <= 10 ; i++ ) {

       for ( j = 1 ; j < i ; j++ ) {

               cout << " ";

       }

          for ( j = i ; j <= 10 ; ++j ) {

                cout << "*";
        }

         cout << endl;

   }


    cout <<"\n";


   int k , l ;

   for (  k = 1 ; k <= 10 ; k++ ) {

       for ( l = k ; l < 10 ; l++ ) {

               cout << " ";

       }

           for ( l = 1 ; l <= k ; l++ ) {

               cout << "*";

           }

       cout << endl;

   }

   system ("pause");
   return 0 ;

}
```

instead of being one below the other like in my code , the output should be side by side like this :

```
*                 ***************     ***************                 *

**                **************       **************                **

***               *************         *************               ***

****              ************           ************              ****

*****             ***********             ***********             *****

******            **********               **********            ******

*******           *********                 *********           *******

********          ********                   ********          ********

*********         *******                     *******         *********

**********        ******                       ******        **********

***********       *****                         *****       ***********

************      ****                           ****      ************

*************     ***                             ***     *************

**************    **                               **    **************

***************   *                                 *   ***************
```

in a way , this hint below should help me use for loop as the problem asked to display the shapes as needed can anyone help ?? thanks alot.

```
// needs additional counter for B and C who rely on decremented counting

    for(int i=1, j=10; i<=10; i++, j--){

        // A

        for(int k=1; k<=10; k++){

           std::cout << ((k <= i) ? '*' : ' ');

        }

        std::cout << "     ";

        // B

        for(int k=1; k<=10; k++){

            std::cout << ((k <= j) ? '*' : ' ');

        }

        std::cout << "     ";

        // C

        for(int k=10; k>=1; k--){

            std::cout << ((k <= j) ? '*' : ' ');

        }

        std::cout << "     ";

        // D

        for(int k=10; k>=1; k--){

            std::cout << ((k <= i) ? '*' : ' ');

        }

        std::cout << std::endl;

    }

}
```

Comment: Populate triangles in a separate 2d array for each maybe? Then concatenate them all four into one 2d array, then print it. (or just print before concatenating, but row by row)

Comment: I'm not familiar with arrays . I should only use covered material which makes thing harder . I'm familiar with loop like while , for and nested but no where further u see ? question gave me this hint which I didnt know how to use it

Comment: You need to modify your loops so that they print both stars *and* spaces

Comment: @RPGillepsie can you give an example using one of the loop  in the program ?? thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

You can pack all the inner loops in the outer loop after each other. Just make sure that they also produce spaces when needed.

For the first two triangles, this would look like this:

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

int main (){

    for ( int i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++ ) {    

        for ( int j = 0 ; j < 10 ; j++ ) {
            if ( j <= i ){
                cout << "*";
            } else {
                cout << " ";
            }
        }

        for ( int j = 0 ; j < 10 ; j++ ) {
            if ( j >= i ){
                cout << "*";
            } else {
                cout << " ";
            }
        }

        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

(running version: http://www.cpp.sh/5zqei )

But the array thing from the comments is a better approach, you should also try that one. If not for the exercise then for yourself.

Edit: changed the loops to 0..9. Get used to that variant, simply so that it is consistent with iterations over containers like arrays.

Comment: thanks . I will have a look on it and try to do the other 2 .